# Start job with meteor job collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, jobs

I am using `meteor-job-collection` (https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection); however, I cannot create a job.

I have a method defined as

```
Meteor.methods( {
  insertItems: function ( dataArray ) {
    check( dataArray, [ Object ] );

    dataArray.forEach( function ( element ) {
      [...]
    } );
  }
} );
```

but the method is very memory demanding, so I want to wrap it inside a job. How do I start this job?

I have tried

```
var job = new Job( Jobs, 'insertItems', data ).priority( 'normal' ).retry(
  {
    retries: 5,
    wait: 15 * 60 * 1000
  }
).delay( 60 * 60 * 1000 ).save();
```

but I get the error

```
Error invoking Method 'jobQueue_jobSave': Internal server error [500]
```

My Job Collection is defined as

```
Jobs = JobCollection( 'jobQueue' );

if ( Meteor.isServer ) {
  Jobs.allow( {
    admin: function ( userId, method, params ) {
      return true;
    },
  } );
}
```

Comment: Look at your server console to get more details on the error

Answer (score 2):

Multiple things are missing from your code.

1 - Make sure you start the job server before submitting any jobs. Call **startJobServer()** on the jobCollection on the server.

```
Jobs = JobCollection( 'jobQueue' );

if ( Meteor.isServer ) {
  Jobs.allow( {
    admin: function ( userId, method, params ) {
      return true;
    },
  } );
  Jobs.startJobServer();
}
```

2 - You need to implement the processing of the job. A job is nothing more than a label with data attached scheduled to run at a certain point in time. The handler implements the job logic. In your case you would need something like this:

```
var workers = Job.processJobs('jobQueue', 'insertItems',
  function (job, cb) {
    insertData = job.data;
    // do anything with the job data here.
    // when done, call job.done() or job.fail()

    job.done(); // when done successfully
    job.fail("with reason or error"); //when failing

    // Be sure to invoke the callback
    // when work on this job has finished
    cb();
  }
);
```

Comment: Now my job says `ready` but is never started nor completed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to implement the job processing itself. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I definitiely needs the workers! :-D Where should this be placed? Maybe I have misunderstood something. I thought I wrote `insertItems` because I had a method with this name. Is this wrong? Do I instead have to create some jobs with `Jobs.processJobs()` and call these jobs/job-methods with `new Job( Jobs, 'job-method-name' ....)`?

Comment: You're right, method `insertItems` isn't called automatically. It is just a name of the job. the `processJobs` method refers to that name. Here you implement the processing of the job. This way you can create different type of jobs in the same job queue. Inside, you can do whatever you want with that job, such as calling a Meteor Method. This code can be put on the client or server. If you want to offload processing from the client, this needs to be placed on the server. Depends what you need. Also, if you define the method on the server, you can call it from the client as well.